# Easier Way to Set Button Hover Icons in C#

Tags: c#

When I am making a lot of buttons, is this the best way, or is there a better way? This code feels sort of clunky.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.MouseEnter += Button_MouseEnter;
button.MouseLeave += Button_MouseLeave;
Button button2 = new Button();
button2.MouseEnter += Button2_MouseEnter;
button2.MouseLeave += Button2_MouseLeave;

void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("buttonHover");
}

void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("button");
}
void Button2_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("button2Hover");
}

void Button2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("button2");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there isn't better way. I would create a custom control with properties "button" and "buttonHover".

Something like this (not tested yet):

```
public class MyBytton : Button
{
    public Image MainImage { get; set; }
    public Image HoverImage { get; set; }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter (EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HoverImage != null)
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = HoverImage;
        }
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void  OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainImage != null)
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = MainImage;
        }
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
        MyBytton my = new MyBytton();
        my.Location = new Point(10, 10); ;
        my.Name = "button1";
        my.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(141, 61);
        my.TabIndex = 0;
        my.Text = "test";
        my.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        my.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("img1.jpg"); 
        my.MainImage = Image.FromFile("img1.jpg");
        my.HoverImage = Image.FromFile("img2.jpg");
```

Comment: Could you give a concise example please?